# VectorPlot not localizing variables

Tags: plotting, vector

Is this a bug or not?

```
u = {{}};
VectorPlot[{1, u^2}, {u, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 0.4}]
```

[image]

The `VectorPlot` works fine if `u = {}` or `u` is cleared. It also works or fails on random-looking things: it works when `u = {1, {1, {}}}` and fails when `u = {1, {{}}}` and so forth.  By "works," I mean it produces the plot of the vector field $(1,u^2)$ that you get when `u` is cleared.

Version 12.0, Mac.

Comment: I think it has to be a bug, based on the line "VectorPlot treats the variables x and y as local, effectively using Block." from the docs.

Comment: There are a handful of particular values for which it fails I could find, include `u = "a";` and `u = "a";` `u = Quantity[1, "Inch"];`, among others.

Comment: @Michael E2 not sure if you tried it in the new version, but it works fine. Just thought to let you know